# React-Bootsrap navbar dropdown not closing

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I'm using React-bootstrap package on my react project.

I tried to use simple navbar with dropdown example from react-bootsrap offical demo page.

Here is the example. Dropdown opening when click to 'dropdown' link but it's not closing when trying to click anywhere outside of dropdown. So it's not behave like on example on demo. What can be problem with that?

```
<Navbar bg="light" expand="lg">
  <Navbar.Brand href="#home">React-Bootstrap</Navbar.Brand>
  <Navbar.Toggle aria-controls="basic-navbar-nav" />
  <Navbar.Collapse id="basic-navbar-nav">
    <Nav className="mr-auto">
        <Nav.Link href="#home">Home</Nav.Link>
      <Nav.Link href="#link">Link</Nav.Link>
      <NavDropdown title="Dropdown" id="basic-nav-dropdown">
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.1">Action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.2">Another action</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.3">Something</NavDropdown.Item>
        <NavDropdown.Divider />
        <NavDropdown.Item href="#action/3.4">Separated link</NavDropdown.Item>
      </NavDropdown>
    </Nav>
    <Form inline>
      <FormControl type="text" placeholder="Search" className="mr-sm-2" />
      <Button variant="outline-success">Search</Button>
    </Form>
  </Navbar.Collapse>
</Navbar>
```

Answer (score 0):

It's probably a little late for this but I had the same issue.  What I finally ended up doing was adding this:

```
    componentDidUpdate() {
        document.getElementById("root").click();
    }
```

This forced a closure as soon as the page was loaded.  This was put into my main component, or app.js if you so choose.

HTH